# Trying to see if a column equals another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some dummy variables and I wanted to see for a column with a df value of 1 has a value of a 0 to the right of that value within the same row. Here is an example of a dataframe and the columns that would return the rows I want. You can see that I would like to result in the the rows with index #1, 2, & 4 because a 0 comes after the 1. It is a big dataframne for the record, so doing the dates hardcoded would be too cumbersome:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'2018-02': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], '2018-03': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], '2018-04': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], '2018-05': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], '2018-06': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]})

result_df = pd.DataFrame({'2018-02': [0, 0, 1], '2018-03': [1, 1, 0], '2018-04': [1, 1, 0], '2018-05': [0, 0, 0], '2018-06': [1, 1, 0]})
```

attempted code:

```
pd.DataFrame({'2018-02': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], '2018-03': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], '2018-04': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], '2018-05': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], '2018-06': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

test_df[[(test_df == 1) & (df_duration.shift(-1, axis=0) == 0)]].head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.shift`:

```
res = test_df[(test_df.eq(0) & test_df.shift(axis=1).eq(1)).any(1)]
```

Output:

```
   2018-02  2018-03  2018-04  2018-05  2018-06
1        0        1        1        0        1
2        0        1        1        0        1
4        1        0        0        0        0
```

It checks for a cell where it is 0 and becomes 1 when gets shifted (i.e., (1, 0) pair in serial view)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are probably the most straightforward, but here's a different approach that might be interesting and more efficient:

If each row only contains 0s and 1s, then the only way for a 0 to NOT occur after 1 is to have a bunch of consecutive 0s, followed by consecutive 1s. We can check for this by taking the rowwise difference. For `[0,0,0,...,1,1,1]` the difference should be all 0s and one 1 where this change occurs so the unique values of the rowwise difference should be `[0,1]`. For any other situation besides `[0,0,0,...1,1,1]`, 1 will have to change back to 0 meaning the unique values of such a row would include the value `-1`.

So this expression will give you all rows where there are consecutive 0s followed by consecutive 1s: `test_df.diff(axis=1).dropna(axis=1).apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x.unique(), [0,1])`

Then all we need to do is negate this and select such indices using .loc:

```
import numpy as np
test_df.loc[~test_df.diff(axis=1).dropna(axis=1).apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x.unique(), [0,1]), axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
2018-02  2018-03  2018-04  2018-05  2018-06
1        0        1        1        0        1
2        0        1        1        0        1
4        1        0        0        0        0
```

Since you mentioned you have a big dataframe, performance might be important to you. I did some benchmarking to compare my answer with the answer by @mozway (method 2) and @Chris (method 3) and it looks like my method is slightly faster after 10000 runs, although I am honestly not sure why.

```
import timeit
setupcode = "import pandas as pd; import numpy as np; test_df = pd.DataFrame({'2018-02': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], '2018-03': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], '2018-04': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], '2018-05': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], '2018-06': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]})"
testcode = ''' 
def test1(): 
    return test_df.loc[~test_df.diff(axis=1).dropna(axis=1).apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x.unique(), [0,1]), axis=1)]
'''
testcode2 = ''' 
def test2(): 
    return test_df[test_df.diff(-1, axis=1).eq(1).any(axis=1)]
'''
testcode3 = ''' 
def test3(): 
    return test_df[(test_df.eq(0) & test_df.shift(axis=1).eq(1)).any(1)]
'''
print(f"my method: {timeit.timeit(stmt=testcode, setup=setupcode, number=10000)}")
print(f"method #2: {timeit.timeit(stmt=testcode2, setup=setupcode, number=10000)}")
print(f"method #3: {timeit.timeit(stmt=testcode3, setup=setupcode, number=10000)}")
```

Output:

```
my method: 0.0006242650000000127
method #2: 0.000695205000000032
method #3: 0.0007448290000000024
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the previous diff per row. 1 followed by 0 has a previous diff of 1:

```
test_df[test_df.diff(-1, axis=1).eq(1).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   2018-02  2018-03  2018-04  2018-05  2018-06
1        0        1        1        0        1
2        0        1        1        0        1
4        1        0        0        0        0
```